# Cloudbees jenkins does not trigger jobs on promotion

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am trying to follow one of Koshuke's apporaches to organize my builds by using job-promotion on cludbees dev@cloud. In his presentation everything worked as a charm (beside running his examples from his own Jenkins instance deployed on localhost and me running jenkins jobs in dev@cloud).

Basically i have a couple of jobs and my main job called *package* within folder *joy* defines promotion process named "promotion-to-e2e-testing" (with criteria being completion of one of downstream jobs and no extra action defined for promotion). From the jenkins dashboard i can see that this promotion was successful. Nevertheless a job (called *e2e-testing* within folder *joy*) being configured with trigger "Build when another project is promoted : Job name: "joy/package", Promotion: "promotion-to-e2e-testing" is not fired !

I have looked at jenkins systems logs (via cloudbees Manage Jenkins link) and i can see:

```
May 20, 2013 6:04:33 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run SEVERE: I/O error in channel s-8770fc61
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
athudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50) Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:59)
at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)May 20, 2013 6:04:26 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: joy » package » promotion » promotion-to-e2e-testing #5 main build action completed: SUCCESS
May 20, 2013 6:04:26 AM hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList log
FINE: Executor #0 for s-8770fc61 : executing joy » package » promotion » promotion-to-  e2e-testing #5 acquired /scratch/jenkins/workspace/joy/package
May 20, 2013 6:04:25 AM hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger setUpPingForChannel
```

By reading from the bottom to the top it seems that SynchronousCommandTransport is thrown after successful promotion. To make sure that throwing the exception is not volatile i have run my jobs a couple of times but still see the same exceptions in logs and my e2e-testing job is not fired.

Anyone can help me with that ? Maybe triggering a jobs by promotion is not available on cloudbees? Or maybe it is because my jobs are stored in a jenkins folder (all jobs being in a single folder) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> configured with trigger *Build when another project is promoted*: Job name: `joy/package`

I suspect you have hit one of the symptoms of [JENKINS-17955](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17955). If my hypothesis is correct, `joy » package` will work as the upstream name even though `joy/package` is really what the plugin ought to be expecting. But I have not yet dug further and tried to reproduce and fix it.

Comment: As I moved all jobs outside folder sth started working - e2e-testing was finally fired. Nevertheless for my "package" job I have the second promotion (promote-to-staging) with criteria being completion of e2e-testing job (which is not downstream job of package job)and this promotion does not happen. On e2e-testing job console i can see: "WARNING: package appears to use this job as a promotion criteria, but no fingerprint is recorded." . It is weird since i enabled both both "Archiving artifacts" and "Record fingerprint to track ..." post build actions in e2e-testing configuration.

Comment: The mentioned bug was fixed in 2.11 by the way.