# promotion after completion of non-downstream job

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

My question is somewhat continuation of [Cloudbees jenkins does not trigger jobs on promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647460/cloudbees-jenkins-does-not-trigger-jobs-on-promotion). To recap: I am using jenking on cloudbees. I have a job named "package" with a couple of promotion processes. The first promotion process "promote to e2etesting"  is configured as: promote after job named "testing" is successfully run. "Testing" is configured as downstream job of "package" job (build other project of post build action section). This promotion works nicely and as soon as "promote to e2etesting" is performed a new job named "e2e-testing" is fired.

My "package" job has other promotion processes, one of them being named "promotion-to-staging" with criteria being : "when the following downstream projects build successfully: e2e-testing". Unfortunately after successful completion of "e2e-testing" (triggered by "promote to e2etesting"), "promotion-to-staging" does not happen.

On "e2e-testing" job console output i can see:

```
WARNING: package appears to use this job as a promotion criteria, but no fingerprint is    
recorded. Fingerprint needs to be enabled on both this job and package. 
See http://hudson.gotdns.com/wiki/display/HUDSON/Fingerprint for more details
```

I have no idea if the warning is related to my problem but on the other side it is weird since i have "record fingerprint of files ..." enabled for "e2e-testing job", and "package" job (being maven job) seems to have it enabled out-of-box - as i click on "passport icon" on artifact built by "package" job i can see it utilization among other jobs.

In jenkins logs i can see:

```
SEVERE: I/O error in channel s-74638b6e 
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel at
hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:59)
at  hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
May 24, 2013 3:43:31 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: e2e-testing #10 main build action completed: SUCCESS
May 24, 2013 3:43:19 AM hudson.slaves.WorkspaceList log
FINE: Executor #0 for s-74638b6e : executing e2e-testing #10 acquired /scratch/jenkins/workspace/e2e-testing
May 24, 2013 3:43:14 AM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: package » promotion » promotion-to-e2e-testing #10 main build action completed: SUCCESS
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`e2e-testing` need not be a configured downstream job of `package` (i.e. kicked off directly as a post-build action), but there need to be a downstream relationship between the *builds* as identified by fingerprints. In other words, some (successful) build of `e2e-testing` must record a fingerprint of an input artifact which matches the fingerprint of an artifact produced by some build of `package`. When that happens, `promotion-to-staging` should be triggered on that build of `package`.

Given the warning message you saw, I suspect that `e2e-testing` either does not record fingerprints, or is recording fingerprints but none matching an artifact produced by `package`. You should be able to check this by browsing the *Fingerprints* link for a successful `e2e-testing` build, verifying that the expected artifact is listed, then clicking on details for that artifact and verifying that it is also listed as being “produced” by a `package` build.

Comment: Below please find artifact fingerprint of successful e2e-testing job run. It shows that given artifact was used by package/testing/e2e-testing jobs (i can not trace if the artifact was produced by package and just used by other jobs) but to me it looks that fingerprints are working fine. Nevertheless promotion-to-staging does not happen.

Comment: Below please find artifact fingerprint of successful e2e-testing job run:  http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/9721/screenshotfrom201305281.png  . It shows that given artifact was used by package/testing/e2e-testing jobs (i can not trace if the artifact was produced by package and just used by other jobs) but to me it looks that fingerprints are working fine. Nevertheless promotion-to-staging does not happen. Since package is maven job i can see an option to fingerprint artifact - does it mean that all artifacts produced by maven jobs are automatically fingerprinted ?